# Simple Angularjs not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I went through two tutorials with different approaches and the same thing is happening. The expressions simply aren't showing up and I everything step by step but it doesn't go the same way.

```
<html data-ng-app = "">
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type = "text" data-ng-model = "name" /> {{ name }}


    <script src = "Script/angular.js"></script>
</body>
```

When executed the {{ name }} is printed out instead of taking the vlue in the variable name.

Comment: Open console (F12) and check the error printed there.

Comment: can you please post this one to pluker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just  exchange the source for the angular script then you example works fine.

```
<html data-ng-app = "">
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type = "text" data-ng-model = "name" /> {{ name }}


    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
</body>
```

Therefore, I would check if the reference to your local copy of the script is correct.

Comment: I think the problem was that i was trying to run it locally, and i guess that's not a thing. I was rather skepticle about trying it this way because i had already downloaded angular. Thank you though (y)

Answer (score 1):

if you see {{name}} 
its means that your angular.js file was not loaded

I put your code in plunker and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me:

```
<html ng-app = "Page">
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Controller as page">
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type = "text" ng-model = "name" /> {{ name }}


    <script src="./js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
            var app = angular.module("Page",[]);

            app.controller("Controller",function(){});
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```